# Can we Convert number to string in C programming?

Tags: c

I have tried this but it doesn't work for me?

Code looks like this:

```
char result[50];

float n= 23.56;

printf(result, "%f", n);

printf("\n The string for the n is %s", result);
```

Output: `The string for the n is`

I didn't get the answer.

Comment: Yes. We can do that.

Comment: Now please explain (to yourself mostly) what each part of `printf(result, "%f", n);` is supposed to do.

Comment: I like to get : The string for the n is 23.56.

Comment: As others have mentioned,`sprintf` will do the job. If you need to convert an `int` to array there is a function called `itoa`.

Comment: This looks like a simple typo.  sprintf, not printf.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sprintf()` instead of `printf()`. Even better, use `snprintf()` which lets you specify the length of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char result[50];

    float f = 23.56;

    // Your code uses printf()
    // printf(result, "%f", f);

    // Use sprintf() instead!
    sprintf(result, "%f", f);

    // Whenever possible, use snprintf()!
    // snprintf(result, 50, "%f", f);

    printf("\n f = %s\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

**Why is `snprintf()` better than `sprintf()`?**
The short answer is that `snprintf()` is safe against buffer overflow attacks.

References:

- `snprintf()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/
- `sprintf()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf instead of print. Like this

```
sprintf (result,"%f",n)
```

Comment: It is `sprintf` actually

Comment: @Suspense Don't use `sprintf()` use `snprintf()` instead.

Comment: yes i have tried sprintf(). It works

Answer (score -1):

If I remember the right syntax:

```
int main()
{
    char result[50];
    float n = 23.56;
    ftoa(n, result, 4);
    printf("\n\"%s\"\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

```html
// C program for implementation of ftoa()
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

// reverses a string 'str' of length 'len'
void reverse(char *str, int len)
{
 int i=0, j=len-1, temp;
 while (i<j)
 {
  temp = str[i];
  str[i] = str[j];
  str[j] = temp;
  i++; j--;
 }
}

// Converts a given integer x to string str[]. d is the number
// of digits required in output. If d is more than the number
// of digits in x, then 0s are added at the beginning.
int intToStr(int x, char str[], int d)
{
 int i = 0;
 while (x)
 {
  str[i++] = (x%10) + '0';
  x = x/10;
 }

 // If number of digits required is more, then
 // add 0s at the beginning
 while (i < d)
  str[i++] = '0';

 reverse(str, i);
 str[i] = '\0';
 return i;
}

// Converts a floating point number to string.
void ftoa(float n, char *res, int afterpoint)
{
 // Extract integer part
 int ipart = (int)n;

 // Extract floating part
 float fpart = n - (float)ipart;

 // convert integer part to string
 int i = intToStr(ipart, res, 0);

 // check for display option after point
 if (afterpoint != 0)
 {
  res[i] = '.'; // add dot

  // Get the value of fraction part upto given no.
  // of points after dot. The third parameter is needed
  // to handle cases like 233.007
  fpart = fpart * pow(10, afterpoint);

  intToStr((int)fpart, res + i + 1, afterpoint);
 }
}

// driver program to test above funtion
int main()
{
 char res[20];
 float n = 34.5;
 ftoa(n, res, 4);
 printf("\n\"%s\"\n", res);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ftoa` is no standard function

Comment: dont work @Filippo Rivolta

Comment: Can we receive any feedback after the scrip has been edited please?